# Is pre-mining of a future block possible?

Tags: blockchain, block, mining-theory

Is it possible to pre-mine next block when everyone is mining current block?

Let's say, if we need 1T hash power to mine (solo / pool) a block in 1 hour, then is it possible to run 1G hash miner for 1000 hours and then use this data as proof of work.

With 1G miner, I am essentially targeting n'th (x + 6000) block in future, hoping to solve it. I will broadcast it as soon as I get hash of n-1'th block.

Comment: Does solving block X+1 if you solved (but did not broadcast) block X count as one of the approaches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be asking if you can mine block X+1 while the network is still working on block X.

**The answer is no**, you can't mine block X+1 until block X has been solved, as each block requires a hash of the previous block to be valid.

Comment: hash(block X) needs to start with (block X+1) mining, or just to broadcast mined (block X+1) ?!

Comment: can you please comment on my previous question. Thanks.

Comment: @vi.su. I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Block X+1 requires a hash from a block X though, which means block X must have been solved already before mining of block X+1 can start.

Comment: thanks. I thought it is also possible to start mining x+1 block, even before block x is mined, and to broadcast x+1 block, We need block x hash (because block x hash is just part of block x+1, not included in the mining calculations).